# Difference between Schmitt trigger IC and IC with Schmitt trigger inputs

Tags: schmitt-trigger

This is the second time I am facing this question. First time I thought the second time will never come.
My question is what is the difference with the Schmitt trigger IC (for example 74AHC1G14) and the inverter with Schmitt trigger inputs (74AUP1G06) in terms of their input characteristics.

For the second IC (74AUP1G06) they say that there are Schmitt triggers at the input but no data about the hysteresis is provided.

When would somebody use explicitly an IC that is labeled as a Schmitt trigger and when an IC with Schmitt trigger inputs?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. They both are just logic chips with Schmitt trigger inputs.

I don't know which datasheet you mean, but for example [this datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74AUP1G06.pdf) contains the hysteresis information.

Answer (score 0):

They look the same to me. According to Diode Inc's datasheets: at 25-deg-C, at VCC=3V,

- 74AHC1G14 positive-going threshold=2.2V (max); negative-going threshold=0.9V (min).
- 74AUP1G06 positive-going threshold=2.2V (max); negative-going threshold=0.9V (min).

The 74AHC1G14 can operate at higher VCC (5V), so its thresholds increase when operated at a higher VCC.